# Is there an etymological connection between the words “gut” (“good”) and “Gott” (“god”)?

Tags: meaning, etymology

Someone told me that there is an etymological connection between the words *gut* (*good*) and *Gott* (*god*).

Is there any truth to such an assertion? I looked at the Oxford English Dictionary under the etymology of the word *god* and it said it comes from the German *Gott*, but notes that the source/origins of that word is otherwise unknown.

Comment: check out Santos Bonacci's work to see a perspective on this important question!

Answer (score 9):

I think it’s evident that there’s **no etymological relation** between *gut* and *Gott* (not even between *good* and *god* for that matter). Along their respective ancestries however, both words share forms of similiar sound (or shape).

- New High German *gut* ←
  Proto-Germanic **gōdaz* ‎← Proto-Indo-European **gʰedʰ-*
- New High German *Gott* ← Proto-Germanic **gudą* ← Proto-Indo-European *ǵʰuto-*

While it’s relatively clear that *gut* originally meant “to be associated” or to “suit”, it is suspected that *Gott* meant something like “invoked idol” in primordial times.

Note that you’ll find competing and even conflicting information. For starters, see the etymology panel in the [DWDS entry for *Gott*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Gott) and particularly the Wikipedia [article dedicated to the word *god*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_%28word%29).

Answer (score 7):

The origin of the word *Gott* (and of its cognates in the other Germanic languages, such as *god* in English) is indeed unknown. There are several competing theories; a discussion of some of them can be found in Pfeifer’s *Etymologisches Wörterbuch* ([DWDS entry](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Gott); the *Etymologisches Wörterbuch* is part of DWDS). However, none of these theories suggests a relationship to *gut* ([DWDS entry](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=gut)).

Answer (score -2):

In Russian бог->god, богатство->goods, and господин->owner, господь->god.
So when referring to a Christian tradition I'd rather imagine that in Germanic it would also be associated with the ownership: das Gut or goods rather then the quality: gut or good.